# wcf rest message inspector url redirect

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, redirect

I'm having trouble with implementing URL redirection using message inspectors for my WCF REST service. The idea is to implement AfterReceiveRequest to change the incoming request to effectively do nothing, and then in BeforeSendReply, make call to another URI which provides the actual service. You can think of this scenario as something where we do not want to break clients, so they continue to use old URIs for invocations, but internally we redirect them to a different URI.

For example, this is what my service contract looks like:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "person/{person}")]
    string GreetMe(string person);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "donothing")]
    string DoNothing();
}
```

And this is the implementation:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GreetMe(string person)
    {
        return string.Format("Hi {0}", person);
    }

    public string DoNothing()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then I'm adding a MessageInspector to endpoint behavior. The AfterReceiveRequest of this inspector is like this:

```
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            OperationContext operationContext = OperationContext.Current;

            if (WebOperationContext.Current != null && WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch != null)
            {
                UriBuilder baseUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BaseUri);
                UriBuilder requestUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri);

                OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["MicrosoftDataServicesRootUri"] = baseUriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
                OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["MicrosoftDataServicesRequestUri"] = baseUriBuilder.Uri.ToString() + "donothing";
                OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To = new Uri(baseUriBuilder.Uri.ToString() + "donothing");
                operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties["Via"] = new Uri(baseUriBuilder.Uri.ToString() + "donothing");
                request.Headers.To = new Uri(baseUriBuilder.Uri.ToString() + "donothing");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Basically, I want to change all incoming requests to go to DoNothing() operation. However, when I run this, I still see that the request makes it to GreetMe method. I attached the debugger and can see that my code in AfterReceiveRequest is getting executed, but I'm not sure why the URI redirection does not happen.

Any ideas?